# Notation of polarization of light

Tags: notation, polarization

Upon my research of polarization of light I stumbled upon the following formula:
[image]

What do the three dots mean? I have never seen them before.
Edit: Found this notation in the book "Nonlinear fiber optics", $P_{NL}$ is the nonlinear polarization component, while $\chi$ is unknown to me (haven't found it, but I assume that it is a tensor for the polarization)

Comment: *Where* did you stumble upon that formula, and what do the variables in the equation denote?

Comment: Updated it as far as possible, thanks for mentioning that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The triple dots denote a tensor-contraction over three indices. This is a generalization of the notation for the scalar product (which is contraction over one index). The three adjacent terms $E$ are implied to form a tensor product.

$\chi^{(3)}$ is third order term of the perturbation expansion of the full (non-linear) susceptibility (more specifically electrical polarizability; in non-linear optics the susceptibility is expanded in perturbation series, while usually one only considers the linear term).

So $\chi^{(3)}$ is a tensor of rank 4 and three of its indices are contracted with the indices of the $E$-fields giving the polarization $P_{NL}$. I guess the first non-zero, non-linear term is cubic because there is usually no effect analogous to diamagnetism for electrical polarization.